# tcpdumping virtual network on the Oracle Virtual Server

Tags: xen, oracle-vm-server

Is there a way to enable proper promiscuous mode in Oracle Virtual Server based virtual network?
It seems like card is getting only some percents of total network traffic.
I have tried all of the network types which are available on the Oracle Virtual Manager infrastructure.

Simplest possible case: "local" virtual network of three hosts, file is being transmitted from one to second host, third host is trying to tcpdump network. File is successfully transmitted, but third host has got only one packet from the start of file transfer.
 I think it should be finetuned by usage of some xl commands. It can be some common problem on all of the Xen based virtualizations.  What should be done to get traffic be seen to other network participants?

All network interfaces  were created like with

```
OVM> create vnic name=capture_network_card network=local on vm id=${id}
```

where 'local' is the name of the  virtual network type.

File transfer console log:

```
1.2.3.6# scp 1.2.3.4:*p ./
/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 57: Unsupported option "gssapiauthentication"
1.2.3.4's password:
file.pp 100% 126MB 110.5MB/s 00:01
```

Tcpdump on the third host:

```
-sh# tcpdump -i eth6

tcpdump: WARNING: eth6: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth6, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
08:42:12.456647 IP 1.2.3.6.37610 > 1.2.3.4.ssh: Flags [S], seq 2743878644, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 10], length 0
^C
1 packet captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

OVM 'local' network:

```
OVM> show network name=local
Command: show network name=local
Status: Success
Time: 2019-04-17 11:13:29,434 EDT
Data: 
  Server Local = true
  Server = b0:3c:4c:3a:75:fe:d5:11:88:cc:18:bb:00:30:c5:db  [vmserver2]
  MTU = 1500
  Role 1 = Virtual Machine
  Vnic 1 = 0004fb0000070000591e972d7b9043d0  [local_card_va11]
  Vnic 2 = 0004fb00000700007d493cbb2938f30e  [local_capture_on_3_29]
  Vnic 3 = 0004fb00000700005d89961ae7d76d23  [local_capture_network_card]
  Vnic 4 = 0004fb000007000075309ee8253700e8  [local_card_va9]
  Id = 105e4d86c5  [local]
  Name = local
  Locked = false
```

There  is some other cards here at present, but they are irrelevant to the problem. I tried to create other  hosts/cards but without any success in traffic capture.

Further findings:

If replay some PCAP files on such a network, capture card will see only some ICMP and ARP packets. It will see other packets only if replay traffic directly to the virtual host network adapter. I determine this adapters on the server through  OVM and OVS consoles:

```
[ovm]# exec 'list network'|grep local
  id:105e4d86c5  name:local
```

So the **105e4d86c5** is the network id.

Searching on the vmserver interfaces from this network **105e4d86c5**

```
[root@vmserver2 ~]# ip a |grep 105e4d86c5
16: 105e4d86c5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
19: vif1.2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master 105e4d86c5 state UP qlen 32
37: vif3.6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master 105e4d86c5 state DOWN qlen 32
44: vif3.6-emu: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master 105e4d86c5 state UNKNOWN qlen 500
```

if I tcpreplay traffic directly to this vif* adapters - their virtual hosts can tcpdump this packets for sure. But, if I run tcpreplay on virtual host and tcpdump on server - there will be no traffic again, tcpdump prints about packets 'dropped by kernel'.

I have very little experience with Xen, but the same configuration in VMWare is working like a charm.

Is there way at all to get working packet sniffing in oracle virtual network?

Comment: I would rephrase mentioning proper promiscuous mode. Promiscuous mode only listens for transmission  of machines in a hub or mirrored switch ports. The question seems to stem more for a lack of understanding how tcpdump and tcp ip works. I would also be wary of virtual environments, some rules might change. Notably the hypervisor can forbid vms from using promisc mode. As for xen, i suspect there also also nuances, but haven't used it for a while.

Comment: it's a vendor specific question: whether oracle vm has option to allow netcard grab al of the network traffic or not.